# Yii2 mysql how to insert a record into a table where column value already exists and should be unique?

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have a table, say 'mytable' that use a "rank" column that is unique. After having created some record where rank is successively rec A(rank=0), rec B (rank=1), rec C (rank=2), rec D (rank=3), rec E (rank=4). 
I need to insert a new record that will take an existing rank, say 1, and modify the rank value of the following records accordingly.
The result being : rec A(rank=0), new rec (rank=1), rec B (rank=2), rec C (rank=3), rec D (rank=4), rec E (rank=5).

How can I do this ? Can this be solved with mysql only or should I write some important bunch of code in PHP (Yii2) ?

Comment: If the rank is existing it cant be unique column into the db... I don't understand why this column must be unique

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no rank is skipped you need to shift existing ranks before saving the new record. To do that you can use `beforeSave()` method of your `ActiveRecord` like this:

```php
class MyModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (!parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($insert) { //only if we are saving new record
        {
            $query = self::find()
                ->where(['rank' => $this->rank]);
            if ($query->exists()) { //check if the rank is already present in DB
                //we will create the query directly because yii2
                // doesn't support order by for update
                $command = static::getDb()->createCommand(
                    "UPDATE " . static::tableName() .
                        " SET rank = rank + 1 WHERE rank >= :rank ORDER BY rank DESC",
                    [':rank' => $this->rank]
                );
                $command->execute();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // ... other content of your model ...
}
```

MySQL allows use of `ORDER BY` in `UPDATE` query, that will help us deal with fact that doing `UPDATE` on table is not atomic and the `UNIQUE` constraint is checked after each row is updated.

It would be more problematic if there are skipped ranks. In that case you will need to shift ranks only until you hit first skipped rank.

Another option might be creating an before insert trigger on the table that would do the rank shifting.

**Note:**

It might be a good idea to also implement `afterDelete` method to shift the ranks in oposite direction when some record is removed to avoid skipped ranks.

**Resources:**

- [\yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::beforeSave()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#beforeSave()-detail)
- [\yii\db\ActiveRecord::updateAllCounters()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#updateAllCounters()-detail) - replaced with direct update
- [MySQL triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)
- [MySQL UPDATE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Comment: Thank you. I guessed it was something like this but I didn't know the updateAllCounters function. I will give this a try.

Comment: Trial succeeded but I had to remove the uniqueness of the colunm rank in the table. Otherwise updateAllCounter fails when trying to increment the first value of rank because of duplicate. E.g 3 has to become 4 but 4 already exists.

Comment: Uhm, i always thought that query in mysql is atomic, i guess it isn't. But i found other way how to do it, i will update my answer.

Comment: @meaulnes I've replaced the use of updateAllCounters with `UPDATE` query that uses `ORDER BY` that should be able to deal with `UNIQUE` index

Comment: If you are using the rank to simply sequence the records, why not use a timestamp? If you really want to use the approach you are using, you could insert the new records with the next sequential number (max + 1) and then render as (max - rank) which will create the order you are looking for.